react-ace Ace editor giving console error UNTRUSTED_TYPES_CHECK_STACK_BELOW
I have been trying a very basic example with Ace Editor using react-ace library and I am getting console error as -- UNTRUSTED_TYPES_CHECK_STACK_BELOW
Following is my code.
 <AceEditor
    mode="json"
    theme="tomorrow"
    name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
    editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
  />


I am using react-ace library -- 11.0.1

Any help would be highly appreciated.
